# I can not save and restore a variable with placeholder in tensorflow

Tags: python

***my codes is as follow:***

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def add_layer(input):
    v2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2], dtype=tf.float32, name='v2'))
    tf.add_to_collection('h0_v2',v2)
    output=tf.matmul(input,v2)
    return output
x1=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
outputs=add_layer(x)
tf.add_to_collection('outputs', outputs)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    x1=np.random.random([2, 2])
    print(sess.run(outputs,feed_dict={x:x1}))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt')
    print("model saved in file:", save_path)
```

**and then another codes is runned:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
x2=np.random.random([2, 2])
print(sess.run(tf.get_collection('outputs',feed_dict={x:x2})))
print('model is loaded')
sess.close()
```

**and then computer tells me that the 'x' is not defined, I do not know what is wrong.**

Comment: But the first code is running without errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would say to do like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt')
x2=np.random.random([2, 2])
print(sess.run(tf.get_collection('outputs',feed_dict={x:x2})))
print('model is loaded')
sess.close()
```

I found this on tensorflow's website. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes，but when I run it twice, a error will be thrown out, said :ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: Variable/Adadelta_1.

Comment: Try to restart the kernel... maybe it helps for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I found a method to solve the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def add_layer(input):
    #v1 = tf.Variable(np.random.random([2, 2]), dtype=tf.float32, name='v1')
    v2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2], dtype=tf.float32, name='v2'))
    tf.add_to_collection('h0_v2',v2)
    output=tf.matmul(input,v2)
    return output
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
outputs=add_layer(x)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
x2=np.random.random([2, 2])
print(sess.run(outputs,feed_dict={x:x2}))
print('model is loaded')
sess.close()
```